# why golang and php gzip results are different

Tags: php, go, gzip

I need gzip data in golang ,and post it to other API Service (wirte with php),but API Server can't ungzip ,why?

why golang and php gzip results are different ?
 thanks in advance

**gzip string "1" :**

1. golang  result :[31 139 8 0 0 9 110 136 2 255 50 4 0 0 0 255 255]
2. php   result :[31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 2 3 51 4 0 183 239 220 131 1 0 0 0 ]

**see demo**

1. [golang code](http://play.golang.org/p/Cm_4ox24NA)
2. [php code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96e3b0c09121442ec7e08abdfd0c204b8030ba63)

Comment: The marked question compares gzip results of **Java** and **Go** examples, but the reason is the same. Compression algorithms are not required to (and often they don't) generate the same result, even if the same app is run on the same input again. What matters is that when they are decompressed, it should give back the exact same result (the original input).

Comment: Potentially the issue could be for different default values of the third parameter for gzcompress... try ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP and ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW

Comment: thanks, i will check the app service , why cna't deccompressed

Comment: I have ask new question : [php can't decompress gzip data by golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759354/php-cant-decompress-gzip-data-by-golang)