# PHP can't decompress gzip data by Golang

Tags: php, go, gzip

Why can't decompress gzip data by Go in my PHP demo, but PHP gzip data to Go is successful? I need post gzip JSON data from Go to PHP API service.

**Test result**

```
 -> |  php   |  go 
---------------------
php |  ok    |  ok
go  |  fail  |  ok
```

**PHP code**

```
class GzipDemo
{
    public function gzen($data, $file){
       $json_data = json_encode($data);
       $gz_data = gzencode($json_data,9);
       file_put_contents($file,$gz_data);
    }

    public function gzdn($file){
       $data = file_get_contents($file);
        $unpacked = gzdecode($data);
        if ($unpacked === FALSE)
        {
            print("failed:".$file."\n");
        }else{
             print($file. " result Data :".$unpacked ."\n");
        }
    }
}

$demo = new GzipDemo();
$file="phpgzip.txt";
$demo->gzen("data",$file);
$demo->gzdn($file);
$demo->gzdn("gogzip.txt");
```

This result:
PHP to PHP okay.
Go to PHP fail.

**Go code**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    gzen("data", "gogzip.txt")
    gden("gogzip.txt")
    gden("phpgzip.txt")
}
func gzen(data string, file string) {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, _ := gzip.NewWriterLevel(buffer, gzip.BestCompression)
    defer w.Close()
    w.Write(b)
    w.Flush()
    ioutil.WriteFile(file, buffer.Bytes(), os.ModePerm)
}
func gden(file string) {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buffer.Write(b)
    r, _ := gzip.NewReader(buffer)
    defer r.close()
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    fmt.Println(file, " result Data:", string(data))
}
```

This result: 
Go to Go okay.
PHP to Go okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with the following changes:

- In your PHP code you want to use `gzdecode` instead of `gzinflate`.  And you don't need this `substr($data, 10)` stuff if you use that.  I didn't read up on how deflate relates to gzip but the simplicity is that `gzencode`/`gzdecode` match what the golang `gzip` package does and what the `gz*` family of GNU command line tools do.
- In your Go code move your gzip.Writer.Close() call to be done before you read from `buffer`. As you can see here: http://golang.org/src/compress/gzip/gzip.go?s=6230:6260#L240 there is some additional stuff that is written to the underlying stream upon close, so in your example above what you are writing is incomplete. (The `defer` statement causes `Close()` to be run after the containing function exits.)  Most likely the Go gzip decoding is managing to decode anyway whereas the PHP implementation is not - in any case you should properly close the stream to your in memory buffer to ensure it is complete before writing it out to a file.

OBLIGATORY NOTE: You are ignoring all of your errors in your Go code.  This code looks like just a test so I won't belabor the point but you definitely want to be doing proper error handling (either reporting the problem to the user or to the caller of your function).

Comment: thank you a lot !   First I don't study php ,the code is not nice. Now I know I can use `gzdecode( $data)` . Second I need close writer . last this code just for test ,I want clear code,so ignore all error